# How do I use a .lib with the "Visual C++ for linux" plugin?

Tags: linux, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, g++

I'm using the [Visual C++ for Linux plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.VisualCforLinuxDevelopment). I can run a basic Hello world without problems. My actual project uses a `.lib`. It compiles fine but I get an error during linking (this is copied from Visual Studio's output pane):

```
ClCompile:
  Starting remote build
  Compiling sources:
  Invoking g++
  g++ -c -x c++ /home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/LinuxProgServ/main.cpp -I /home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/include/libuv -I /home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/../include/lubuntu -I "/home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/../include/lubuntu/x86_64-linux-gnu" -g2 -gdwarf-2 -o "/home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/obj/x64/Debug/main.o" -Wall -Wswitch -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -Wconversion -W"return-type" -Wparentheses -W"no-format" -Wuninitialized -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -O0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fthreadsafe-statics -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11
  main.cpp
  Done compiling '/home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/LinuxProgServ/main.cpp'
Link:
  Linking objects
  Invoking ld
  g++ -o "/home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/bin/x64/Debug/LinuxProgServ.out" -Wl,--no-undefined /home/devbox/projects/LinuxProgServ/obj/x64/Debug/main.o -llibuv.lib
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibuv.lib
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

libuv.lib is specified in Project Properties>Linker>Input>Library Dependencies. I tried the following without success:

1. Copy the lib to /home/devbox/projects/lib and add that directory to
   the linker command with -L, both using Visual Studio's additional
   library folder field and directly in the Additional command line
   options field. This results in the same final command.
2. Copy the lib to the output directory and set it to be copied
3. Add the local Windows path to Visual Studio's additional library folders
4. Add the linux path from #1 to Visual Studio's additional library folders
5. Try with another library

I made the same project but for Windows just to be sure and it works.

Am I missing something? Obviously I could just run the commands myself or use any variant of *make but that's not the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a library to g++ with `-l`, g++ helpfully prefixes the name you give with `lib` then looks for a file of that name with a `.so` or `.a` extension on the library search path. By convention, shared libraries (dlls) have the `.so` extension and static libraries the `.a` extension.

The route of least resistance would be to build your library with the `.a` extension, i.e. `libuv.a` then specify it to the VCLinux project library dependencies as `uv`. And specify the library search path with `-L`, as you do in your step 1.

<strike>Alternatively, you can put the full path of the library on the g++ link command line, without `-l` prefix, i.e. `/home/devbox/projects/lib/libuv.lib` and g++ will use it in the same way it uses other object files. Set via `Linker/All Options/Additional Options`.</strike>
Update: on reflection, this second approach won't work. Although g++ (gcc) will accept the library as an input when specified with its fully qualified path, the library must appear **after** the program object files for references to be resolved. Unfortunately there is no control over positioning of `Additional Options` in VCLinux which always puts them at the front of the parameter list on the g++ command line, i.e. before the object file(s). :(

And, at the risk of stating the obvious, the library must be built on Linux with g++ and be located on a path visible to g++ when linking your program.